# Finding the digital root of a number

Tags: python, algorithm

i tried to implement function that finds the digital root of a number(it is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.) but for some reason it returned none  if the function make a recursive call to itself

```
import functools
def digital_root(n):
  r=functools.reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y),list(str(n)));
  if r//10<1:
   return r
  else:
   digital_root(r)
```

Comment: it is required for reduce function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't returning any value in the else clause, hence it gives None

```
def digital_root(n):
  r=functools.reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y),list(str(n)));
  if r//10<1:
   return r
  else:
   return digital_root(r)
```

A more readable form would be:

```
def root(n):
    d_sum = 0
    for i in str(n):
        d_sum += int(i)
    if dsum<10:
        return d_sum
    return root(d_sum)
```

Without recursion:

```
def root(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(map(int, str(n)))
    return n
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the lack of `return`, you didn't look up the reduced, closed-form algorithm:

```
return 9 if (r % 9 == 0) else (r % 9)
# Parentheses are unneeded, but added for readability
```

The "old-school" name for digital sum was "casting out nines"; you take the number's modulo base `b-1`, where `b` is the original number base.  9 for decimal, 15 for hex, etc.

Comment: Nice workaround solution, based on maths. Not suitable for programming assignments though

Comment: That depends on the assignment specs.  Recursion was given only as a definition of "digital root", rather than an implementation requirement.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for mentioning it, but that's not perfect (try with 189 for example).  Happy 4000th answer!

Comment: All multiples of 9 would've failed this approach. Added an edit to the answer for this case

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you try to achieve, but I guess that you would like to *return* the outcome of your recursive call, so change the last line of your example to:

```py
   return digital_root(r)
```